# How does operator delete work in qt5 with qObjects

Tags: qt, memory-leaks

In c++ when u allocate memory, u should always delete them (in Destructors for example). But in qt u often don't worry about deleting objects. Qt does it for u. IDE does not correctly show all the memory leaks. I saw code somewhere like this:

anyLayout->addWidget(new QLabel(QString("text")));

will this QLabel be truly memory leak?

The same question about adding the same way QListString to QComboBox.

Comment: No, this is not a memory leak. There's a concept of [object ownership](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/objecttrees.html). That is if a QObject is owned by another (parent) QObject, the parent will delete all its children. Now, QWidget inherits QObject and also follow this delete-children rule. According to the docs [addItem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qlayout.html#addItem) and [addWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qlayout.html#addWidget) take ownership over the added items and the layout itself is owned by its parent widget. Therefore for QWidgets you don't need to delete them manually.

Comment: You can connect the [destroyed](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qobject.html#destroyed) signal to a custom slot in your app and set a debugger breakpoint in this slot to check for the moment when the widget gets deleted and to see the stack trace. And I didn't understand the question about the "_QListString_"

Answer (score 4):

No, QWidgets added to a layout will be automatically parented to the layout. This is explained [here](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-dev/qlayout.html#addItem).

> Note: The ownership of item is transferred to the layout, and it's the layout's responsibility to delete it.

When the parents are cleaned up, so will the children. I would encourage you to read about [Object Trees & Ownership](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/objecttrees.html) in Qt.